# msbuild error MSB4019: trying to import .csproj.*.props

Tags: c#, msbuild

When I try to use dotnet / msbuild, I get the following error:

```
error MSB4019: unable to find the imported project "MyProject.csproj.*.props". Check if the Import statement "MyProject.csproj.*.props" is correct and if the file exists. [MyProject.csproj]
```

(I translated it from my native language, it's maybe not the "real" output that the CLI would give you if your language is set on English.)
The file "MyProject.csproj" exists. But there isn't any file with the ".props" extension in my project folder.
I don't use VS, I'm under Arch Linux and installed mono and dotnet through `pacman`.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The csproj is a text file that can be opened in notepad.  Usually child projects have full path names where the project is located.  I often edit the csproj to change the full path names to relative path names so I can make backup copies of main project and child projects by copying the root folder.  I would check if the props exist on the release files and see if they are in a different folder.

Comment: I didn't create any props file, and didn't manually changed the .csproj. Even when I do `dotnet new console` and then `dotnet restore`, the error I mentioned occurs.